# Tensorflow on Hexagon DSP unclear issues

Tags: tensorflow, hexagon-dsp

I am follow instruction to build Android application with Tensorflow engine on Hexagon DSP.

My device is Pixel 1.

1. libhexagon_controller.so - there is no compilation problem with **android_Release** mode , but when I trying to build **android_Release_aarch6** i have linkage problem :

   warning: libadsprpc.so, needed by /Tensorflow_Hexagon/tensorflow-master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/hexagon/libs/libhexagon_controller.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

I resolve it with adding -ladsprpc to Makefile in  tensorflow/contrib/makefile.
If ladsprpc nedeed for android_Release_aarch64 why in android_Release it's ok ?

2.I follow steps to generate sign test shared library -${QUALCOMM_SDK}/docs/Tools_Signing.html

my problem is with `adb push output/testsig-0x<serial number> /system/lib/rfsa/adsp/`

I am getting `adb: error: failed to copy 'testsig-xxxx.so' to '/system/lib/rfsa/adsp/': remote couldn't create file: Is a directory`

What to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: No, as I understand  Hexagon DSP and GPU (OpenCL) on  Google Pixel 1,2 are not available for user application.